# Stop Mediawiki tinymce editor to convert html code

Tags: php, html, tinymce, mediawiki

I'm just started to working with mediawiki file.
I installed Bootstrap extension there  and added jquery also.
Everything was fine but In tinymce editor when i use html tag like , after submit it's just vanished that tag & left only plain text.
I searched similar issue since 2 days on internet but can't find solution that work for me.
I've tried html entities, cleanup, valid_elements and many more things.
Is there any solution ?

any suggestions will be appreciated.
Ask me if you want to see something.

Answer (score 0):

You will find Mediawiki uses markdown for editing and viewing content (not HTML). HTML will normally be removed by the system and you're left with what looks like plain text.

To enable HTML, insert `$wgRawHtml = true;` into the LocalSettings.php file in your main MediaWiki directory and the wiki will allow you to insert raw unchecked HTML.

See [MediaWiki HTML Restriction](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/HTML_restriction#:%7E:text=MediaWiki%20restricts%20the%20use%20of,at%20includes%2Fparser%2FSanitizer) and [$wgRawHtml Manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRawHtml) for more details.